# ExecJS::ProgramError in Rails tutorial demo app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm following demo app tutorial on http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#sec:planning_the_application. After generate scaffold for users. when i try to access localhost:3000/users. I got the following error on ExecJS

```
Started GET "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-01 13:35:37 -0500
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 458ms

ActionView::Template::Error (ExecJS::ProgramError
(in /Users/kylec/apps/demo_app/app/assets/javascripts/users.js.coffee)):
3: <head>
4:   <title>DemoApp</title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8: </head>
9: <body>
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in    `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___642905557_18993590'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

The page renders if I take out #line 6 <%= javascript_include_tag "application"%>
I'm running ruby 1.9.3, rails 3.2.7, osx 10.5.8

Comment: have you included execjs gem in your gemfile ?

Comment: Duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548935/problem-with-execjs-doing-michael-hartl-tutorial-on-windows-execjsruntimeer

Answer (score 1):

You need to look in your Gemfile. Find this line and uncomment it.

```
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
```

Comment: I tried to do gem install therubyracer and it complained that I had an older version of gcc. While i was struggling to get new gcc compiled, I realized I had two version of gem installed - gem and gem1.9. The error went away when I did gem1.9 install therubyracer and there's no more ExecJS error! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have faced with similar problem.
I have installed node.js and add path to ruby and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case  [this was the solution:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421547/rails-execjsprogramerror-in-pageshome#comment46410989_28436913)
I just modified gemfile downgrading coffee-script-source to 1.8.0, and voila! Here is my gemfile:

```
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

# Downgrade coffee-script source
gem 'coffee-script-source', '~>1.8.0'

# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Comment: Finally, thank you for adding full details of changes to your gemfile (I'm new to ruby/rails).  Other answers have been a bit misleading and confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on windows, this definitely works :

In your /app/views/layouts/application.html.erb line 5 and 6, change the first parameter application to default.

I met the same problem, too for my situation, I don't know why, but it only happen on Windows. The parameter application works on web server.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows:

In your /app/views/layouts/application.html.erb line 5 and 6, change the first parameter application to default.

I met the same problem also,

it is helped me:
change 'application' for 'default'

my code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>AppSample</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```