# Error on using Bootstrap Sass in rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm working on a simple ruby on rails application and I am getting the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'process' of undefined (in/home/saasbook/Documents/projects/Bookkeeper/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass)`

The Extracted source is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Bookkeeper</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %> //Highlighted error line in extract
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

This error occurred after I added Bootstrap Sass by Using the Bootstrap Sass plugin and following this [tutorial](http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/integrating-rails-and-bootstrap-part-1/)

Below the extract its stated that the error is at:

`app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__226809778_88444660'`

**My code**

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Bookkeeper</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>  //Highlighted error line in extract
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

 </head>
 <body>
    <%= yield %>
 </body>        
</html>
```

**application.css.sass**

```
/*
* This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
* listed below.
*
* Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
* or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
*
* You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
* compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
* defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
* file per style scope.
*
*= require_tree 
*= require_self
*/

@import "bootstrap-sprockets"
@import "bootstrap"
```

**The page shows this title in the red border on top, is this any help?**

`ExecJS::ProgramError in Portal#index`

Comment: If you remove the contents of `application.css.sass` do you still get the error?

Comment: @Magnuss tried doing that, but I am still getting the same error. If you notice that though the line above extract states that the error is in `application.css.sass` but it is actually in `application.html.erb`, editing the question to make that clear.

Comment: Is the above a copy/paste error, or is your `head` indented within your `html`...and the `title`, `stylesheets`, `javascripts`, etc indented within the `head`?

Comment: @JustinLicata it is the ready-made view made by rails so I don't expect there to be an error of that sort. Also, I never knew that indentation in HTML can cause errors.

Comment: Just had to ask :)...you never know...Are you able link us to the code on GitHub..since it's a tutorial? In order to properly help debug this with you, seeing the code will help tremendously.

Comment: @JustinLicata sorry can't add the link to my github, followed the tutorial to add Sass as I have never used Sass before but it is part of a bigger project and the repo is private but I have added the relevant code.

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11782229/2456549

Comment: @JustinLicata Tried that, still getting the same error :/

Comment: Versions of rails, ruby, etc. ?

Comment: That is a very strange bug, I was getting it after creating a new Rails 4.2 app with Bootstrap with Autoprefixer. I just reloaded the app a couple of times while commenting out autoprefixer or bootstrap gem and it magically started to work.

Comment: @crackedmind rails 4.1.5, 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [i686-linux]

Comment: @bodrovis so did you have both of them uncommented when it started to work or not?

Comment: I just took my previous github file and again installed bootstrap-rails and it seems to be working fine. @JustinLicata I followed your advice and uncommented rubyracer, thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with version 5.0 of the autoprefixer-rails gem. Try downgrading to 4.0.2.2.

https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer-rails/issues/47

This will pop up if you are using Node instead of RubyRacer as your JS runtime.

EDIT - 
 This has been fixed in the latest version of autoprefixer.

```
bundle update autoprefixer-rails
```

Comment: Instead of downgrading `autoprefixer-rails` gem version adding `gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby` helped me get rid of the reported error. Thanks.

Comment: @JiggneshhGohel Thank you, adding 'therubyracer' worked for me.

Comment: Instead of downgrading the version, installing rubyracer made it work for me as @JiggneshhGohel suggested

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in the latest release of autoprefixer. Upgrade using the following command -

```
bundle update autoprefixer-rails
```