# Rails no longer compiles and serves up my application.scss file

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I am using Rails 4.2.0 and all of a sudden my style tag in my application.html.erb layout doesn't render the application.css anymore.

In my layout I have:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
```

Which produces this error:

```
Showing /****/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'processor.process')
  (in /****/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss)
```

Which line 5 is simply the stylesheet_link_tag above.

If it helps my Gem file looks like this:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.0'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'bootstrap_form'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', :require => 'bcrypt' 
gem 'lodash-rails'
gem 'angular-rails-templates'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'refile', require: ['refile/rails', 'refile/image_processing']
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'RedCloth'
gem 'sass-json-vars'
```

Removing the stylesheet_link_tag makes the application run fine. Keeping the tag but emptying the application.scss file does not.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding `gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby` to your Gemfile....and of course bundle install and restart your server.

Comment: That fixed the error. The font files are missing from Bootstrap SASS but I can work with that now. At lease I can debug it.

Would you mind explaining why Googles V8 engine would fix this?

Comment: Add `@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';` before importing `bootstrap` or custom variables in your application.scss to fix the font issue.

Comment: Ok thanks for that! Did you want to put your comments in as an answer so I can vote you up?

Comment: hope everything is working for ya now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the `process` error, add `therubyracer` to your Gemfile. Credit to [this S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946932/error-on-using-bootstrap-sass-in-rails).

```
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
```

and to fix the Bootstrap glyphicons issue, import `bootstrap-sprockets` prior to importing Bootstrap or custom variables in your **application.scss**

```
@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
```

For reference to missing icons, [here is a nice snippet](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails) from the Bootstrap-sass README.