# Ruby on Rails installed on windows getting ExecJS::ProgramError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, rubygems

I'm working on a project which I normally work on Mac OSX. I'm on ruby MRI V.1.9.3-p194 and rails v.3.2.8.
but, for the time being, there has been a need to collaborate the project source code with another team member who's using windows.

I proceeded on to set up everything on my colleague's windows machine and almost everything seems to work quite well, the same ruby and rails framework version are used. I managed to get 'bundle install' to pass by having most of their dependencies resolved. (So, you can imagine that the versions of gems have got updated from those on my Mac Machine)
I also have node.js installed on my colleague's machine in order to make ruby able to run javascript.

A while later, it seemed I was able to start the web server using "bundle exec thin start" and it's starting without any error. The other reason, I'm quite sure my setup's been coming in the right way
because I can retrieve model records via rail console beautifully. But I'm only getting one error, every time I try to browse to the app on the web browser.

Every time I'm getting node.js dependency error "cannot find module 'stylus'"
that even prevents me from getting the login page loaded.

here is a snapshot of the error I get:

[image]

also, I'm happy to share you my Gemfile, so it could give you more clues what actually goes wrong? it can be found below:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem 'rubyzip', '< 1.0.0'
gem 'roo','1.12.1'
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.11'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.1.2'
gem 'haml', '3.1.7'
gem 'thin', '1.4.1'

group :development do
  gem 'capistrano', '2.13.4'
end

gem 'devise', '2.1.2'
gem 'devise-async', '0.5.0'
gem 'cancan', '1.6.8'
gem 'simple_form', '2.0.4'
gem 'cocoon', '1.1.1'
gem 'inherited_resources', '1.3.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'
gem 'mechanize', '2.5.1'
gem 'delayed_job', '3.0.4'
gem 'paperclip', '3.4.0'
gem 'spreadsheet', '0.6.4.1'
gem 'geocoder', '1.1.6'
gem 'whenever', '0.8.2'
gem 'american_date', '1.0.0'
gem 'money','5.1.1'
gem 'rets','0.5.1'
gem 'haversine','0.3.0'
gem 'capybara'
gem 'poltergeist'
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
gem 'redis'
gem 'execjs','2.0.0'


group :assets do
  gem 'stylus', '0.7.1'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.3.0'
end
```

What should I do to get this to work? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Updated:**

I updated my question rgrd Brad suggestion accordingly.
I've performed as suggested. but when I have node.js uninstalled, I rather got another error like below "The node.js runtime is not available". any idea?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [ExecJS::RuntimeError on Windows trying to follow rubytutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial)

Comment: You don't need node, on Windows, fwiw.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I tried uninstalling node.js as suggested. but this time I'm getting another error 'The Node.JS runtime isn't available to Stylus.Ensure that the 'node' (or 'nodejs') executable is present in your $PATH.' I have my question updated with such error snapshot accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421547/rails-execjsprogramerror-in-pageshome?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I changed from coffee-script-source 1.12.2 to 1.8.0 in Gemfile.lock file.
ex) coffee-script-source (1.8.0)

And then, in cmd, I put a command like 'bundle install'.
If you do not have a bundle, you can install bundle such as

```
gem install bundle
```

Finally, turn off your rails server and turn on again.

Thank you.