# javascript_include_tag 'application' not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

In my `application.html.haml` I have `= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true`

Which is throwing the error: `TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
(in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/turbolinks-2.5.1/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)`

My `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` is:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.tablesorter
//= require_tree .
```

and my gemfile includes:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
```

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While not positive if this will work for you I just dealt with a similar issue.  Specifically for setting the application.html.erb javascript_include_tag to 'application'

What I read was that in newer versions of rails that include coffee-script-source that is a version greater than 1.8.0 it causes issues on Windows systems.  The solution is to downgrade to 1.8.0.

Source: [Rails ExecJS::ProgramError in Pages#home?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421547/rails-execjsprogramerror-in-pageshome)

Credit to Michael Petch in the above link.

coffee-script source >= 1.9.0 don't work properly under Windows. You can do this: gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0' to force 1.8.0 and then issue bundle update coffee-script-source –  Michael Petch Mar 17 at 0:07

Answer (score 0):

Above solution by jordan fits perfectly..another solution is change your line to:
   *javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true*

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy.

Do not change application for default.

Do not move gems trying install coffee-script-source or 'execjs'

Just Install [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and

remove the line(assets/javascript/application.js):

```
//= require_tree .
```

restart rails and reload the page.

Go!.