# Deletion in RAILS using method: :delete

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and following the tutorial https://mackenziechild.me/12-in-12/12/. I have problems in deleting posts in the app [The rails app allows to create, edit, update, destroy ***posts***(which have a title, a link and a description)]. When ***destroy*** button is clicked, instead of redirecting to ***home*** page, the ***DELETION Confirmation message is not shown*** and I think it keeps reloading the page. Also I noticed that the ***id** of the post changes every time when I hit the destroy button*. When I checked the home page (that lists all posts), the count remains the same and nothing is deleted.

FYI, I have attached my code snippet of show.html.haml

```html
%h1 Inspirations (SHOW)

%h1= @post.title
%p= @post.link
%p= @post.description

%p= @post.__id__

= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(@post)
= link_to "Destroy", post_path(@post), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?"}
= link_to "Home", root_path
```

And my ../app/views/layouts/application.html.erb file is as follows

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Muse</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

Also my ../app/assets/javascripts/application.js is as follows

```js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**Delete Method code in Controller**

```html
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  ....
                                             
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

  def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :link, :description)
  end
```

***Some of my observations***

*My Home Page before deletion*
[image]

*Deleting Dummy Post*
[image]

*Dummy Post's ID changed upon hitting Destroy button*
[image]

*But when checking the Home page (After deletion), still all posts are listed*

Please help me where I went wrong, thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't know where you found `__id__`, but it contains the *id* of a Ruby object, not a database row. Database row is in simple `id` and should not change. As for the problem -- `jquery-ujs` seems to be missing in your app's JavaScript.

Comment: Please add the code of the `delete` method of the controller, and logs.

Comment: I have included the `delete` method of the controller, please check..

Comment: @D-side what can be done to fix the `jquery-ujs` related problems ??

Comment: I think your default.js file doesn't have jquery_ujs `<%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>` Include 
`//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs` in default.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to load `default.js`, which doesn't exist. Your call to `javascript_link_tag` should in fact be

```
 javascript_link_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
```

Your call to `stylesheet_link_tag` is similarly wrong although this is not related to your problem.

Comment: But when I changed from 'default' to 'application' in ../app/views/layouts/application.html.erb, it throws the `ExecJS::ProgramError in Posts#index` error :( Initially I had the ExecJS problem and in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421547/rails-execjsprogramerror-in-pageshome# I saw the answer to fix the execJs error ..

Comment: Then there's some other problem with your app that previously you weren't seeing because it wasn't using your application.js at all

Comment: Any other ways of solving the `ExecJS::ProgramError` @Frederick

Comment: @SteveJobs sudo apt-get install nodejs

Comment: @SteveJobs not from the information given. feels like a separate question to me (but have a search first- lots of questions on that here)

Comment: I am using Windows @Pardeep Dhingra and thatz why so much problems :/

Comment: @SteveJobs have you tried this http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows

Comment: @Pradeep Thx a lot. All works fine all of a sudden after a couple of restarts :) May be I think, I installed node.js but I didn't restart my system :)