# :method put: not working instead Get method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, get, put

So I am trying to use the following route:

```
<%= link_to like_post_path(@post), :method => :put do %>
```

But I don't know why is using `GET` method instead of `PUT`

```
 No route matches [GET] "/posts/1/like"
```

makes no sense to me..

myroutes.rb:

```
 resources :posts do
    member do
        put "like" => "posts#upvote"
        put "dislike" => "posts#downvote"
    end
```

Comment: Try using `button_to` instead of `link_to`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using correct format and your code is should generate something like this:

```
<a data-method="put" href="...">
```

From your routes error message we can conclude that it is not being sent using `POST` with `_method=put` params. So, the problem must be that you did not include jQuery and Rails jQuery extension javascript files.

An easy fix would be to include `application.js` file (jquery and rails js extension are included by default) in your page.

Comment: This is a great suggestion, make sure data-method="put" is set, and makes ure you are requering `jquery_ujs` in your *application.js*.

Comment: That was it!! Thank you so much. The problem was my Jquery and Rails Query due to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421547/rails-execjsprogramerror-in-pageshome

Answer (score 0):

[link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) signature :

```
link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)
```

According to the doc, :method belongs to the options hash.

calling

```
<%= link_to like_post_path(@post), :method => :put do %>
```

results in putting into

- name : like_post_path(@post),
- options: nil,
- html_options: { method: :put }

From [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Hash.html)

Hashes are also commonly used as a way to have named parameters in functions. Note that no brackets are used below. If a hash is the last argument on a method call, no braces are needed, thus creating a really clean interface:

**EDIT**

```
<%= link_to like_post_path(@post), { method: :put } do %>
```

leads to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Wouldn't `options` will be `{ :method => :put }` and `html_options` be `nil`?

Comment: My mistake, edited answer with a correct solution. (options = { method: :put } is what is needed.)