# Loading CSS and JS files in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

I have recently been converted to the Ruby on Rails side so I am new to the art of the asset pipeline and ruby on rails in general. The problem that I am having at the moment is that when I try to load my ruby on rails page up it is getting a 404 error on my `default.js` and my `default.css`. These two files are in the directory `app/assets/javascripts` and  `app/assests/stylesheets` respectively.

I believe that this problem is caused by my `stylesheet_link_tags` and `javascript_link_tags` inside my `application.html.erb`. Below you can see my `application.html.erb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Loadtest</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu">

</head>
<body>
<div id = "content">
    <%= yield %>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

At the beginning the link tags had `application` after them but this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421547/rails-execjsprogramerror-in-pageshome) led me to believe that changing them to `default` would fix the problem.

The error that occurs when I change `default` back to `application` is the following

> ```
> ExecJS::ProgramError in Application#home
> Showing c:/Users/***/Desktop/loadtest/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:
> TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
>     Rails.root: c:/Users/aterra/Desktop/loadtest
> ```

I have not changed my `application.js` or `application.css` in any way and look how they would look when you build a rails application.

If you need to see my application controller it looks like this

> ```
> class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
>   # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
>   # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
>   protect_from_forgery with: :exception
>   def home   
>   end
> end
> ```

Any help in solving this question would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for you time.

EDIT:

I resolved my problem by changing `default` to `application.css` and `application.js` respectively. After that I went into my application.js folder and added `=require turbolinks` without the `//` and then voila it started working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can require your JS and CSS files in your `application.[js|css]`
In your application.js, append `//= require default`
and in your application.css, append `*= require default`, default being the name of your JS/CSS files respectively.
You can learn more about the Assets Pipeline here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Answer (score 1):

By default Rails will look for `application.js` for the manifest. If you want to use `default.js` you have to implicitly instruct Rails to look for it:

Try adding the following to `/config/initializers/assets.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( default.js )
```

Comment: Do I then change my application.js and application.css to default.js and default.css?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.