# Redmine without bitnami ruby on rails on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I instaled and configured all and i had this error, when i was trying to enter to my site:

i put http:\localhost:3000  and showed me that error;

```
Showing C:/xampp/htdocs/dev-ruby/redmine/app/views/layouts/base.html.erb where line #15 raised:

TypeError: El objeto no acepta esta propiedad o método

Rails.root: C:/xampp/htdocs/dev-ruby/redmine
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/helpers/application_helper.rb:1192:in `stylesheet_link_tag'
app/views/layouts/base.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_layouts_base_html_erb___1528543778_53155600'
lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:63:in `sudo_mode'
```

i looked at my base.html.erb file and the error stops in those lines :

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.0', 'application', 'responsive', :media => 'all' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'rtl', :media => 'all' if l(:direction) == 'rtl' %>
<%= javascript_heads %>
```

I looked at the files those files:application_helper.rb and fordawable.rb.

But i don't know how solucinate correctly it with the database or gemms file.
I use my own "solution", which was changing the "base.html.erb" changing the lines with that other:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/stylesheets/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.0.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/themes/classic/stylesheets/application.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/stylesheets/responsive.css" />
```

But that it isn't the correct solution. If somebody could give the correct solution i apprecite it. i 'm searching if i find something i'll post it.

I am find that post who solucionates part of the problem

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421547/rails-execjsprogramerror-in-pageshome
```

Changing application for default on that line:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.0', 'default', 'responsive', :media => 'all' %>
```

But now it appears a problem with that other line:

```
<%= javascript_heads %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is on that post:

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421547/rails-execjsprogramerror-in-pageshome
```

An we can put on out Gemfile the this:

```
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
```

and then run that command:

```
 bundle update coffee-script-source
```