# Ruby on Rails: coffee-script-source locked at 1.10.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, rubygems, version, bundle

While following the [Ruby on Rails Getting Started Tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) on Windows 7, in the hello rails section of the tutorial when loading localhost:3000 I got the error

> Object doesn't support this property or method

from the line

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

in application.html.erb

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421547/rails-execjsprogramerror-in-pageshome) had success downgrading coffee-script-source to version 1.8.0 by adding the line:

```
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
```

to the Gemfile and doing a bundle update. However, when I try to run the bundle update in the cmd line I'm getting the error:

> You have requested:   coffee-script-source = 1.8.0
>
> The bundle currently has coffee-script-source locked at 1.10.0. Try
>   running 'bundle update coffee-script-source'
>
> If you are updating multiple gems in your Gemfile at once,  try
>   passing them all to 'bundle update' Run 'bundle install ' to install
>   missing gems.

I've tried all the suggestions in the error and have restarted the command line multiple times.

I also did a gem uninstall coffee-script-source 1.10.0 and then a gem install coffee-script-source 1.8.0 with the same result.

Any advice on how to unlock a gem from its current version and use the method of setting the version in the Gemfile?

Comment: I also have similar problem but its with sqlite 1.3.10. I've both sqlite 1.3.10 and 1.3.11 but Gemlock file has the 1,3,10 version. So I deleted all occurrences of sqlite3 from Gemlock and Gemfile (because I don't use sqlite. I use postgres). Still no luck. If you want to give it a try, keep a backup of Gemlock and Gemfile and then proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Open Gemfile.lock at your locate project ex : C:/Ruby/Project/Gemfile.lock.
Find coffee-script-source (1.10.0) and change to coffee-script-source (1.8.0).
Then run *bundle install* again

Comment: This didn't work for me. I get this error:
`>ruby bin\rails bundle install`

`Could not find coffee-script-source-1.8.0 in any of the sources`

`Run 'bundle install' to install missing gems.`

Does this have anything to do with
`coffee-script (2.4.1)`

`coffee-script-source`

`execjs`
in the Gemfile.lock file?