# windows - Ruby on Rails ExecJS::ProgramError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, execjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hImbS.jpg)

I have a problem to run my ruby on rails simple blog.

Can I solve this problem on Windows OS?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the answer here - [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421547/rails-execjsprogramerror-in-pageshome?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I changed from coffee-script-source 1.12.2 to 1.8.0 in Gemfile.lock file. ex) coffee-script-source (1.8.0)

And then, in cmd, I put a command like 'bundle install'. If you do not have bundle, you can install bundle such as 'gem install bundle'.

Finally, turn off your rails server and turn on again.

Thank you.