# How to solve "ActionView::Template::Error (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8):"

Tags: utf-8, ruby-on-rails-5.1, argument-error

experts,

I was following a book's example to build my first Blog system on RoR.  My OS is Win10, Ruby is 2.4.2p198 and Rails is 5.1.4.  After activating Rails Server, I connected to localhost:3000/users.  Then I encounter below error:

ArgumentError in Users#index
Showing C:/Users/joeychou/hello_rails/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #7 raised:

invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

And it highlights the error line as below:

> 

On rails server, the error messages are as below:

> ActionView::Template::Error (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8):
>       4:     HelloRails
>       5:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
>       6:
>       7:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
>       8:     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
>       9:       10:
>
> app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7:in
>   `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___655117387_94495480'

Please advise how to solve this issue so that I can move on.  Any help is deeply appreciated!

Regards,Joey

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer!

coffee-script source >= 1.9.0 don't work properly under Windows. You can do this: gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0' to force 1.8.0 and then issue bundle update coffee-script-source

Please refer to below link for details.
[Rails ExecJS::ProgramError in Pages#home?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28421547/rails-execjsprogramerror-in-pageshome?answertab=votes#tab-top)